# How to modify the notification receiver in Google Cloud Messaging?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I have been developing an Android Messenger using **Google Cloud Messaging APIs**. I have been following the tutorials given on http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html. I am able to successfully receive the notifications on the correct device. But i'm not able to change the notification's content.

I have made a Message class which is what i was actually sending. This message class includes the basic details of the message. I have added **sender_name** and **message_body** as additional fields which were not there in GCM example.

**Message.java**

```
private final String collapseKey;
private final Boolean delayWhileIdle;
private final Integer timeToLive;
private final Map<String, String> data;
private final Boolean dryRun;
private final String restrictedPackageName;
private final String sender_name;
private final String message_body;
private final String TAG = "Akshay Messenger";
```

I can't post the entire code because it's too lengthy. get and set methods are also implemented for the respective fields in this class.

Taking an random example, the final body passed to the Http post method looks like following

**String body passed to Http post Method**

```
  registration_id=this_is_the_registration_id&delay_while_idle=0&collapse_key=Akshay&sender_name=sfvshh&messaage_body=dhbvsh&time_to_live=108
```

The function used for sending the post request is

**Sender.java**

```
protected HttpURLConnection post(String url, String contentType, String body) throws IOException
{
    Log.i(TAG, "Sender Class Making a HTTP Post request to a given url using a content .");

    if (url == null || body == null)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "Sender Class URL is null or body is null.");

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("arguments cannot be null");
    }

    if (!url.startsWith("https://"))
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "Sender Class URL does not use https: " + url);
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "Sender Class Sending POST to " + url);
    Log.i(TAG, "Sender Class POST body: " + body);

    byte[] bytes = body.getBytes();
    HttpURLConnection conn = getConnection(url);

    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(bytes.length);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", contentType);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + key);

    OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();

    try
    {
        out.write(bytes);

        Log.i(TAG, "Sender Class bytes : " + new String(bytes));
    }
    finally
    {
        close(out);
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "Sender Class HTTP Post object : " + conn);
    Log.i(TAG, "Sender Class HTTP Post Object OutStream Object " + out.toString());

    return conn;
}
```

The class used for receiving the notification is as follows :

**GCMIntentService.java**

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "GCM Intent Service Inside GCMIntentService class.");

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    Log.i(TAG, "GCM Intent Service extras.toString() : " + extras.toString());

    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if (!extras.isEmpty())
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "GCM Intent Service Message recieved.");

        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType))
        {
            sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
        }

        else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType))
        {
            sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString());
        }

        else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType))
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "GCM Intent Service Message recieved in a correct format.");

            sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());

            Log.i(TAG, "GCM Intent Service Received: " + extras.toString());
        }

        else
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "GCM Intent Service Message Sent taking back the control.");
        }

    }
}

private void sendNotification(String msg)
{
    Log.i(TAG, "GCM Intent Service Notificaton Manager called.");

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm).setContentTitle(TAG).setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg)).setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

After i click on send button which is there on **MainActivity** i can receive the notification but all extra attributes are missing. The notification looks like following :

[image: Snapshot of notification received]

All other atributtes are missing. Any help would be greatly acknowledged. I have already wasted a lot of time on this but still stuck on the same issue.

The Logcat looks like this (I'm posting only the relevnat part of it):

**Logcat**

```
08-29 14:43:47.237: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Main Activity Main Activity Inside Main Activity Application started.
08-29 14:43:47.247: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Main Activity Checking for Google Play Services.
08-29 14:43:47.297: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Main Activity Google Services SDK found.
08-29 14:43:47.297: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Main Activity Getting the registration ID for the device.
08-29 14:43:47.297: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Main Activity Getting the GCM Preferences Context Variables.
08-29 14:43:47.297: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Main Activity Getting the App Version.
08-29 14:43:47.307: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Main Activity App version = 1
08-29 14:43:47.307: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Main Activity Registeration ID found, Registeration ID = THIS_IS_MY_REGISTRATION_ID
08-29 14:43:47.307: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Main Activity Resuming the activity.
08-29 14:43:47.307: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Main Activity Checking for Google Play Services.
08-29 14:43:47.307: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Main Activity Google Services SDK found.
08-29 14:43:47.307: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Main Activity Getting the registration ID for the device.
08-29 14:43:47.307: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Main Activity Getting the GCM Preferences Context Variables.
08-29 14:43:47.307: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Main Activity Getting the App Version.
08-29 14:43:47.307: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Main Activity App version = 1
08-29 14:43:47.307: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Main Activity Registeration ID found, Registeration ID = THIS_IS_MY_REGISTRATION_ID
08-29 14:43:58.218: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Main Activity Send Button Pressed.
08-29 14:43:58.258: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): message_content : ghjkl
08-29 14:43:58.298: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Main Activity Sending the registration ID to Backend Server.
08-29 14:43:58.298: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Main Activity sender_name : asdf
08-29 14:43:58.298: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Main Activity message_body : ghjkl
08-29 14:43:58.328: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Sender Class API Key Recieved : THIS_IS_THE_API_KEY
08-29 14:43:58.328: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Sender Class sendNoRetry function called.
08-29 14:43:58.328: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Message Converting message object to string.
08-29 14:43:58.328: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Message CollapseKey not null
08-29 14:43:58.328: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Message timeToLive not null
08-29 14:43:58.328: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Message delayWhileIdle not null
08-29 14:43:58.328: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Message sender_name not null
08-29 14:43:58.328: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Message message_body not null
08-29 14:43:58.328: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Message final builder.toString() : Message(collapseKey=Akshay, timeToLive=108, delayWhileIdle=false, sender_name=asdf, message_body=ghjkl)
08-29 14:43:58.328: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Sender Class Message message : Message(collapseKey=Akshay, timeToLive=108, delayWhileIdle=false, sender_name=asdf, message_body=ghjkl)
08-29 14:43:58.328: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Sender Class String registrationId :  THIS_IS_MY_REGISTRATION_ID
08-29 14:43:58.328: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Sender Class delayWhileIdle bit is not null passing to body.
08-29 14:43:58.328: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Sender Class collapseKey bit not null passing to body.
08-29 14:43:58.328: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Sender Class sender_name is not null passing to body.
08-29 14:43:58.328: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Sender Class message_body is not null passing to body.
08-29 14:43:58.328: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Sender Class timeToLive bit not null passing to body.
08-29 14:43:58.328: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Sender HTTP requestBody : registration_id=THIS_IS_MY_REGISTRATION_ID&delay_while_idle=0&collapse_key=Akshay&sender_name=asdf&messaage_body=ghjkl&time_to_live=108
08-29 14:43:58.328: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Sender Class Making the Http Post request.
08-29 14:43:58.328: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Sender Class making a HTTP Post request to a given URL.
08-29 14:43:58.328: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Sender Class Making a HTTP Post request to a given url using a content .
08-29 14:43:58.328: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Sender Class Sending POST to https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send
08-29 14:43:58.328: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Sender Class POST body: registration_id=THIS_IS_MY_REGISTRATION_ID&delay_while_idle=0&collapse_key=Akshay&sender_name=asdf&messaage_body=ghjkl&time_to_live=108
08-29 14:44:05.535: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Sender Class bytes : registration_id=THIS_IS_MY_REGISTRATION_ID&delay_while_idle=0&collapse_key=Akshay&sender_name=asdf&messaage_body=ghjkl&time_to_live=108
08-29 14:44:05.535: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Sender Class HTTP Post object : com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpUrlConnectionDelegate:https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send
08-29 14:44:05.535: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Sender Class HTTP Post Object OutStream Object com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport$FixedLengthOutputStream@44944cc8
08-29 14:44:05.535: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Sender Class Post request completed.
08-29 14:44:06.215: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): conn.getInputStream() : com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport$ChunkedInputStream@44949468
08-29 14:44:06.215: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Sender Class Status code : 200
08-29 14:44:06.215: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Sender Class Successfull message status return code.
08-29 14:44:06.215: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Sender Class inside getAndClose function.
08-29 14:44:06.215: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Sender class getAndClose stream com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport$ChunkedInputStream@44949468
08-29 14:44:06.225: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Sender Class inside getString function.
08-29 14:44:06.225: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Sender Class responseBody : id=0:1409303399939497%ca7e668b7504ac97
08-29 14:44:06.225: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): lines.length : 1
08-29 14:44:06.225: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Sender Class TOKEN_MESSAGE_ID match found.
08-29 14:44:06.225: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Sender Class Checking for messageId = 0:1409303399939497%ca7e668b7504ac97 in Result Class.
08-29 14:44:06.225: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Inside Result.Builder.build()
08-29 14:44:06.225: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Sender Class result = [ messageId=0:1409303399939497%ca7e668b7504ac97 ]
08-29 14:44:06.225: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Sender Class Message created successfully.
08-29 14:44:06.225: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Main Activity Sender function called.
08-29 14:44:06.225: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): Main Activity message sending status : Sent message msgID : 1 Message : ghjkl
08-29 14:44:06.446: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): GCM Intent Service Inside GCMIntentService class.
08-29 14:44:06.446: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): GCM Intent Service extras.toString() : Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=256]
08-29 14:44:06.446: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): GCM Intent Service Message recieved.
08-29 14:44:06.446: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): GCM Intent Service Message Sent taking back the control.
08-29 14:44:06.516: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): GCM Intent Service Inside GCMIntentService class.
08-29 14:44:06.516: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): GCM Intent Service extras.toString() : Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=208]
08-29 14:44:06.516: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): GCM Intent Service Message recieved.
08-29 14:44:06.516: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): GCM Intent Service Message recieved in a correct format.
08-29 14:44:06.516: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): GCM Intent Service Notificaton Manager called.
08-29 14:44:06.516: I/Akshay Messenger(2909): GCM Intent Service Received: Bundle[{from=678478691968, android.support.content.wakelockid=2, collapse_key=Akshay}]
```

Answer (score 0):

extras.toString()

You are trying to display an object. That's why you see a special code, who is a String version of your object. That's not the content.

First, your have to get content, and after you can display it.
I don't know the extra type content, maybe a String or an array?
Try to use extras.getXXX("XXX") before displaying.